# How can I translate the email template to diffrent lang?

Tags: laravel

my app is multi lang `(AR,EN)` and I need to make the email template also mutli lang based on the lang that the user open the app like if it's ar send ar same thing with en

in my template I just used

```
@lang('site.hello')
```

I have two files

```
/resources
/lang
    /en
        /site.php
    /ar            
       /site.php.
```

the rresult of my email is like this:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: https://lokalise.com/blog/laravel-localization-step-by-step/

Comment: can you please show the whole code and also the translation files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel allows you to send mailables in a locale other than the current language, and will even remember this locale if the mail is queued.

To accomplish this, the `Mail` facade offers a `locale` method to set the desired language. The application will change into this locale when the mailable is being formatted and then revert back to the previous locale when formatting is complete:

```
Mail::to($request->user())->locale('es')->send(
    new OrderShipped($order)
);
```

**User Preferred Locales**

Sometimes, applications store each user's preferred locale. By implementing the `HasLocalePreference` contract on one or more of your models, you may instruct Laravel to use this stored locale when sending mail:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\HasLocalePreference;

class User extends Model implements HasLocalePreference
{
    /**
     * Get the user's preferred locale.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function preferredLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }
}
```

Once you have implemented the interface, Laravel will automatically use the preferred locale when sending mailables and notifications to the model. Therefore, there is no need to call the `locale` method when using this interface:

```
Mail::to($request->user())->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but the balde of email how will be translated?

Comment: You said that in your template you only have `@lang('site.hello')` so that's the text to be translated.

Comment: Pls see this image https://ibb.co/XZndWtJ  why the h1 does  not print as html tag?

Comment: Where do you have this code? It already escapes the parameters of the question.

Comment: see this balde code of email  https://ibb.co/DGVCH34 just print normally

Comment: You need to specify `html` key in the first parameter: `Mail::send( ['html' => 'emails.newinvoice'], ['text' => $emailtext]` As I said before, you should create a new question, since this is another problem. Your problem in this question is one of translation, not tags.

Comment: Hi sir, I tried this way for user model and it's perfect but when I used the same method for admin method it does not work like User model! Did you try it for Multi Model  ?